# Slow Assets Listing in CP

Tags: assets, control-panel

Our client has created a lot of folders and sub-folders to keep their assets organised. I would guess they've made around 700 to 800!! (Basically two folders for each post)

The assets page in the CP loads very slow now - is there anything I can do to speed this up?

Comment: To clarify, I mean the Assets page in the admin system is going very slow.

Comment: Edited your question, Glenn.

Comment: Cheers Christian :)

Comment: Edited my answer below :)

Comment: Sorry Glenn, I misread your text again! This time I definitely have no answer :) I'll delete all the below to attract more others!

Comment: Thanks for trying anyhow! I'm guessing there's a SQL query running for each folder which is causing the slowdown.

Comment: I profiled the CP admin page, and it runs 432 DB queries - too many I would suggest.

Comment: The profiler shows the total number of queries, but it's also sorted by the worst performing ones at the top... how long are those taking to execute?

Comment: Have you identified the bottleneck yet?

Answer (score 4):

The first step to diagnose would be to determine where the bottleneck is.

If you enable [devMode](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#devMode), you'll see database profiling information in your browser's console, including the SQL executed for each query along with the total number of queries executed.

Those queries will be ordered by the slowest performing ones at the top.  If there are multiple, slow performing queries that are taking up the majority of the time it takes to load the page, then there is likely something we could do in Craft to optimize performance in your scenario and you should contact us at support@buildwithcraft.com and send along a database dump so we can try to reproduce.

If the database queries look like they are not the issue, then the next likely culprit is disc access times.  If these folders/files are in the cloud (S3, Rackspace, etc.), or you're using NFS for your file system, then those could be slowing down the request as well.